# How can i have same parameter for input and output in stored procedure which is called?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

**T-SQL part**

```
create PROCEDURE SPROC_GetTrail
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
      @AccountId INT ,
      @SchemePlanCode INT ,
      @Todate OUTPUT 

END
```

**c# part**

```
  db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("io");
                getCommissionReconMisCmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("SPROC_GetTrail");
                db.AddINParameter(getCommissionReconMisCmd, "@Id", DbType.Int32, AId);---
```

This shoud be used as  in parameter and output parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Database.AddParameter method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb748682.aspx).
The third method's parameter is the direction of your sql param. So you can use [InputOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x5e8bsf) enum value.